# Mips Invalid language element

Tags: compiler-errors, mips, quadratic-programming

Here is the code:

```
.file   1 ""
   .section .mdebug.abi32
   .previous
   .nan   legacy
   .module   fp=32
   .module   nooddspreg
   .abicalls
   .rdata
   .align   2
$LC1:
   .ascii   "There are two roots : %f,%f\012\000"
   .align   2
$LC2:
   .ascii   "There is one root : %f\012\000"
   .align   2
$LC3:
   .ascii   "There are two complex roots : %f +/- %f\012\000"
   .text
   .align   2
   .globl   roots_of
   .set   nomips16
   .set   nomicromips
   .ent   roots_of
   .type   roots_of, @function
roots_of:
   .frame   $fp,72,$31       # vars= 24, regs= 2/2, args= 24, gp= 8
   .mask   0xc0000000,-12
   .fmask   0x00300000,-8
   .set   noreorder
   .cpload   $25
   .set   nomacro
   addiu   $sp,$sp,-72
   sw   $31,60($sp)
   sw   $fp,56($sp)
   swc1   $f20,68($sp)
   swc1   $f21,64($sp)
   movz   $31,$31,$0
   move   $fp,$sp
   .cprestore   24
   swc1   $f12,72($fp)
   swc1   $f14,76($fp)
   sw   $6,80($fp)
   lwc1   $f2,76($fp)
   lwc1   $f0,76($fp)
   nop
   mul.s   $f2,$f2,$f0
   lwc1   $f4,72($fp)
   lw   $2,%got($LC0)($28)
   nop
   lwc1   $f0,%lo($LC0)($2)
   nop
   mul.s   $f4,$f4,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,80($fp)
   nop
   mul.s   $f0,$f4,$f0
   sub.s   $f0,$f2,$f0
   swc1   $f0,32($fp)
   lwc1   $f0,32($fp)
   mtc1   $0,$f2
   nop
   c.lt.s   $f2,$f0
   nop
   bc1f   $L7
   nop

   lw   $3,76($fp)
   li   $2,-2147483648           # 0xffffffff80000000
   xor   $2,$3,$2
   mtc1   $2,$f0
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f20,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,32($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   mov.d   $f12,$f0
   lw   $2,%call16(sqrt)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,sqrt
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,24($fp)
   add.d   $f2,$f20,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,72($fp)
   nop
   add.s   $f0,$f0,$f0
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   div.d   $f0,$f2,$f0
   cvt.s.d   $f0,$f0
   swc1   $f0,36($fp)
   lw   $3,76($fp)
   li   $2,-2147483648           # 0xffffffff80000000
   xor   $2,$3,$2
   mtc1   $2,$f0
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f20,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,32($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   mov.d   $f12,$f0
   lw   $2,%call16(sqrt)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,sqrt
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,24($fp)
   sub.d   $f2,$f20,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,72($fp)
   nop
   add.s   $f0,$f0,$f0
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   div.d   $f0,$f2,$f0
   cvt.s.d   $f0,$f0
   swc1   $f0,40($fp)
   lwc1   $f0,36($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f2,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,40($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   swc1   $f0,20($sp)
   swc1   $f1,16($sp)
   mfc1   $7,$f2
   mfc1   $6,$f3
   lw   $2,%got($LC1)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC1)
   lw   $2,%call16(printf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,printf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,24($fp)
   b   $L8
   nop

$L7:
   lwc1   $f0,32($fp)
   mtc1   $0,$f2
   nop
   c.eq.s   $f0,$f2
   nop
   bc1f   $L5
   nop

   lw   $3,76($fp)
   li   $2,-2147483648           # 0xffffffff80000000
   xor   $2,$3,$2
   mtc1   $2,$f0
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f20,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,32($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   mov.d   $f12,$f0
   lw   $2,%call16(sqrt)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,sqrt
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,24($fp)
   add.d   $f2,$f20,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,72($fp)
   nop
   add.s   $f0,$f0,$f0
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   div.d   $f0,$f2,$f0
   cvt.s.d   $f0,$f0
   swc1   $f0,36($fp)
   lwc1   $f0,36($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   mfc1   $7,$f0
   mfc1   $6,$f1
   lw   $2,%got($LC2)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC2)
   lw   $2,%call16(printf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,printf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,24($fp)
   b   $L8
   nop

$L5:
   lw   $3,76($fp)
   li   $2,-2147483648           # 0xffffffff80000000
   xor   $2,$3,$2
   lwc1   $f0,72($fp)
   nop
   add.s   $f0,$f0,$f0
   mtc1   $2,$f2
   nop
   div.s   $f0,$f2,$f0
   swc1   $f0,44($fp)
   lw   $3,32($fp)
   li   $2,-2147483648           # 0xffffffff80000000
   xor   $2,$3,$2
   mtc1   $2,$f0
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   mov.d   $f12,$f0
   lw   $2,%call16(sqrt)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,sqrt
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,24($fp)
   mov.d   $f2,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,72($fp)
   nop
   add.s   $f0,$f0,$f0
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   div.d   $f0,$f2,$f0
   cvt.s.d   $f0,$f0
   swc1   $f0,48($fp)
   lwc1   $f0,44($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f2,$f0
   lwc1   $f0,48($fp)
   nop
   cvt.d.s   $f0,$f0
   swc1   $f0,20($sp)
   swc1   $f1,16($sp)
   mfc1   $7,$f2
   mfc1   $6,$f3
   lw   $2,%got($LC3)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC3)
   lw   $2,%call16(printf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,printf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,24($fp)
$L8:
   nop
   move   $sp,$fp
   lw   $31,60($sp)
   lw   $fp,56($sp)
   lwc1   $f20,68($sp)
   nop
   lwc1   $f21,64($sp)
   addiu   $sp,$sp,72
   j   $31
   nop

   .set   macro
   .set   reorder
   .end   roots_of
   .size   roots_of, .-roots_of
   .rdata
   .align   2
$LC4:
   .ascii   "Quadratic Solver\000"
   .align   2
$LC5:
   .ascii   "a: \000"
   .align   2
$LC6:
   .ascii   "%f\000"
   .align   2
$LC7:
   .ascii   "b: \000"
   .align   2
$LC8:
   .ascii   "c: \000"
   .text
   .align   2
   .globl   main
   .set   nomips16
   .set   nomicromips
   .ent   main
   .type   main, @function
main:
   .frame   $fp,48,$31       # vars= 16, regs= 2/0, args= 16, gp= 8
   .mask   0xc0000000,-4
   .fmask   0x00000000,0
   .set   noreorder
   .cpload   $25
   .set   nomacro
   addiu   $sp,$sp,-48
   sw   $31,44($sp)
   sw   $fp,40($sp)
   move   $fp,$sp
   .cprestore   16
   movz   $31,$31,$0
   lw   $2,%got($LC4)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC4)
   lw   $2,%call16(puts)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,puts
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   nop
   lw   $2,%got($LC5)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC5)
   lw   $2,%call16(printf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,printf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   addiu   $2,$fp,24
   move   $5,$2
   lw   $2,%got($LC6)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC6)
   lw   $2,%call16(__isoc99_scanf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,__isoc99_scanf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   nop
   lw   $2,%got($LC7)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC7)
   lw   $2,%call16(printf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,printf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   addiu   $2,$fp,28
   move   $5,$2
   lw   $2,%got($LC6)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC6)
   lw   $2,%call16(__isoc99_scanf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,__isoc99_scanf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   nop
   lw   $2,%got($LC8)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC8)
   lw   $2,%call16(printf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,printf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   addiu   $2,$fp,32
   move   $5,$2
   lw   $2,%got($LC6)($28)
   nop
   addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC6)
   lw   $2,%call16(__isoc99_scanf)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,__isoc99_scanf
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   lwc1   $f0,24($fp)
   lwc1   $f2,28($fp)
   lwc1   $f4,32($fp)
   nop
   mfc1   $6,$f4
   mov.s   $f14,$f2
   mov.s   $f12,$f0
   lw   $2,%got(roots_of)($28)
   nop
   move   $25,$2
   .reloc   1f,R_MIPS_JALR,roots_of
1:   jalr   $25
   nop

   lw   $28,16($fp)
   move   $2,$0
   move   $sp,$fp
   lw   $31,44($sp)
   lw   $fp,40($sp)
   addiu   $sp,$sp,48
   j   $31
   nop

   .set   macro
   .set   reorder
   .end   main
   .size   main, .-main
   .rdata
   .align   2
```

Here are the errors i receive in MIPS:

```
Error in C:\Users\***\Desktop\School Stuffs\***\Quadratic solver.asm line 5 column 14:    .module   fp=32
Invalid language element: fp=32
Error in C:\Users\***\Desktop\School Stuffs\***\Quadratic solver.asm line 24 column 22:    .type   roots_of, @function
Invalid language element: @function
Error in C:\Users\***\Desktop\School Stuffs\***\Quadratic solver.asm line 289 column 18:    .type   main, @function
Invalid language element: @function
Assemble: operation completed with errors.
```

Im trying to make a quadratic solver that excepts multiple inputs and uses special phrases but i keep get these errors. I cant find any reason as to why the errors pop up. Any help would be great!

Comment: What does _"in MIPS"_ refer to? A compiler (which one)? A simulator (which one)?

Comment: Note that if you're trying to do something like taking GCC assembly output verbatim and run it in SPIM/MARS, that won't necessarily work.

Comment: I am using MARS, is there a conversion from GCC to MARS?